# segmentation error when joining 2 height balanced tree in C

Tags: c, join, tree, height

I am trying to join 2 height balance trees. for that purpose, I am writing join() function in C. I have done everything as per as instruction but for something, it is showing segmentation error. I understand that segmentation error happen when  there is a bad pointer. I am trying to code in C. I could not figure out where is the bad pointer. I could not understand where did I do wrong. in the code, there is the part 2 and 2.1 in join() function. If I could do that, rest of the parts are pretty much identical. Please let me know where is the error and mistake in my code. please do not give any rude comment, I am learning advanced data structure. thank you in advanced.

```
// I have 2 trees tree1 and tree2. this part is the part when I am joining. there are other parts in the code, but other parts are identical to this part of the code. If I could figure out what I did wrong here, I can figure out for the rest part 

    // join() function
    tree_node_t *join(tree_node_t *tree1, tree_node_t *tree2, key_t separating_key)
    { tree_node_t *common_root, *tmp2, *new_node, *tmp_node, *tmp1, *up;
    int finished;
        //------------------introduction----------------------------------------------
        // we have 2 height balanced tree tree1 and tree2. these 2 trees are arguments. 

        // all keys in tree1 smaller than all keys of tree2

tree1->key < tree2->key;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------part 1----------------------------------------------------
while(abs(tree1->height - tree2->height) <= 1){
    common_root = get_node();// adding a common root 
    common_root->left = tree1;// putting tree1 at left
    tree1->upper = common_root;
    common_root->right = tree2;// putting tree2 at right
    tree2->upper = common_root; 
    common_root->key = separating_key;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------part 2------------------------------------------------------
while(tree1->height <= tree2->height - 2){
    tmp2 = tree2;
    /*while(tmp2->left != NULL){
        tmp2 = tmp2->left;
    }*/
    while(tmp2->left != NULL && tmp2->height <= tree1->height){
        // -------------------------start of part 2.1----------------------------
        while(tmp2->left != NULL && tmp2->height == tree1->height && tmp2->upper->height == tree1->height + 2){
            up = tmp2->upper;
            new_node = get_node();
            new_node->height = tree1->height + 1;
            up->left = new_node;
            new_node->right = tmp2;
            new_node->left = tree1;
            new_node = tmp2->upper;
            up = new_node->upper;
            new_node->key = separating_key;
            up->height = tree1->height + 2;
        }
```

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger to find out where exactly the segmentation fault happens? That would of course be very helpful information.

Comment: no i did not run it in a debugger. I am using dev C++ to run it. Can you please tell me which debugger is good? sorry I am pretty much a rookie

Comment: Without complete code no one else will be able to debug. And without debugging whatever anyone replies back would be a guess.

Comment: Ihave run that inthe debugger, at line common_root->left = tree1; it is showing debugging error and if i do common_root->left == tree1; then this whole loop runs infinitely